# Horizontally center 3 divs of 3 cols

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a scenario where I need to center 3 divs of col3 in a row. When calculating, the answer shows 1.5, but what is the proper way of overcoming this challenge?

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-3" style="height: 50px; background-color: red">
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3" style="height: 50px; background-color: green">    
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3" style="height: 50px; background-color: orange">      
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/25558/

`col-md-offset-2` is messing this up because it leaves `col-1` for the other end. If there was `col-md-offset-1.5` that would be brilliant but apparently no :(

I tried adding paddings and margins and it started becoming very messy, and thought I am directing to the wrong way.

What is the proper way of center the 3 divs without any hacky way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've come to a solution by erasing the offset class from the first inner div, assigning that particular `.row` container an additional class (`.x` in my example) and adding the following CSS for that class:

```
.x {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 12.5%;
}
```

Here is a codepen with the complete code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bwRZyJ

Answer (score -1):

Try removing offset, and changing 3 for 4.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4" style="height: 50px; background-color: red">

  </div>
   <div class="col-xs-4" style="height: 50px; background-color: green">

  </div>
   <div class="col-xs-4" style="height: 50px; background-color: orange">

  </div>
</div>
```

This puts 3 divs in a row, taking 33% of screen each one

UPDATE:

```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
        <div class="col-xs-3" style="height: 50px; background-color: red">

        </div>
         <div class="col-xs-3" style="height: 50px; background-color: green">

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3" style="height: 50px; background-color: orange">

        </div>
      </div><!--row-->
    </div><!--container-->
```

Comment: This is not what I asked for, I want to keep the same width as col-3, not col-4. Obviously, I know to do col-4. It's messing up the sizes

Comment: To clarify you want them all the same width, but centred?

Comment: 3 divs with col-3 horizontal centered?